# how to make partitions before installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

my laptop is having 320GB hard disk. I want partition it with

1. 195 GB as one part(here i want install os),
2. 4GB for swap
3. 70GB as one partition,
4. 50 GB as one partition.

I'm new to do this partition setup. Can anyone please tell me how to do it simply and give me step by step procedure?

Comment: 13.04 is not supported - please do not install an unsupported operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [How to Partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition). This will detail everything you need to know. It is a complicated topic, so please review the referenced help article to fill the gaps in your knowledge before proceeding. Ask a new question if you have more specific questions.